# In ExtJS, how can I create a panel and have it hover above a TabPanel?

Tags: extjs

I have a viewport with a tab panel in it. I'm trying to create a standard panel dynamically and make it visible. I'm able to create the panel and isVisible() returns true after calling doLayout on the viewport but the panel is not visible on the screen. Is there any way to make it visible (i.e., to hover above the tab panel)?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "above" the TabPanel? Do you mean a panel inside a particular tab, or maybe a dialog box?

Answer (score 2):

If you create the panel as a child of the document body and position it absolutely it should show above your existing layout.  You could also (more easily) use an Ext.Window to do this.